# QWeb template check object is empty

Tags: odoo, qweb

I am facing problem while showing the data from database into Qweb Template of odoo v8.

The codes follows:

The controller gives me object from database : like  stock.quant(), the object is from stock_quant table. In this scenario the object is empty. Now i have to check if the object is empty in template. so i tried following :

My Controller: quant.py

```
quant = { get value from table }
return request.render('test', {'quant':quant})
```

in my template i have to check if quant is empty or not, so i tried :

```
<t t-if="quant is Empty" />  # doesn't work
<t t-if="quant is False" />  # doesn't work
```

also checked other way around

```
<t t-if="quant is not Empty" />  # doesn't work
<t t-if="quant is not False" />  # doesn't work
```

Can someone help me in determining how to check object is empty in Qweb Template.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just try simply,

```
<t t-if="not quant">
    <!-- your code -->
</t>
```

And suppose you want to check any other relational fields of that object then you should check like that,

```
<t t-if="not quant or not 'relational_field_name' in quant">
    <!-- your code -->
</t>
```

Answer (score 1):

You using the wrong comparison operator.

In python [`is` compares `identity`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), hence if the value is `{}` or `None` your check will fail even if these values are always boolean falses.

Simply use `not quant` and whatever value will be ok.